# Возможно ли поместить атрибут тега в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Есть `<img id=...>`. Нужно базовыми средствами js поместить id этого изображения в буфер по `ctrl+click`. **Это реально? Если да, то как?**

На основании полученного ответа сделал такую универсальную функцию:

```
function Copy(event, value){
    if (event.ctrlKey){
        var copy_buffer = document.createElement('div');
        copy_buffer.textContent = value;
        copy_buffer.style.position = 'absolute';
        copy_buffer.style.left = '-1000px';
        copy_buffer.style.top = '-1000px';
        document.body.appendChild(copy_buffer);
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(copy_buffer);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        document.execCommand('copy');
        document.body.removeChild(copy_buffer);
    }
}

<img onclick="Copy(event, this.name);" ...
```

Ещё раз спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

```js
document.getElementById("smth").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var cp = document.getElementById("cp");
  cp.textContent = event.target.id;
  
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(cp);

  var selection = window.getSelection();        
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  
  document.execCommand('copy');
})
```

```css
#cp {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<img id="smth" src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" />
<div id="cp"></div>
```

Comment: Идея ясна. Спасибо!